# How do I highlight a certain word in a label?

Tags: c#, label, highlight

I have been watching a couple of videos and I've noticed that you can highlight or set the BackColor for every word it finds in a RichTextBox, I tried doing this with a Label which is what I'm working with on my project but I can't use Label.Find and Label.SelectionBackColor etc. Is there a way I could search a word in my label and highlight it?

Comment: are you dealing with web app?

Comment: labels in Windows Forms (which i think you are using) dont support that kind of styling

Comment: Would it be an option using a TextBox and limiting the controls like editing and highlighting and then using the code i have found?

Comment: @DanielJones look at my answer, you can do exactly that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a workaround, create a RichTextBox and use it as a label.

Set these properties to make it look like a label:

```
richTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
richTextBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
richTextBox.BackColor = SystemColors.Control; // or whatever your background color is
```

work around to disable User selection:

```
richTextBox.Enabled = false;
richTextBox.SelectAll();
richTextBox.SelectionColor = SystemColors.ControlText; // or whatever you want the default text color to be
// you have to set the color or else it will be gray because of Enabled=false
```

Edit: i just tried it, after `SelectAll();` and `SelectionColor = SystemColors.ControlText` any changing or adding of Text keeps it black (unless the current `SelectionStart` is at a point of the text where the color is different

Comment: The label I'm using is being constantly updated with new text, is this a problem?

Comment: shouldn't be a problem, are you changing the text or adding the text, or both?

Comment: I am adding to the text by re-writing the whole Label + new information, should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use two different foreground/background colors in a label. You might split up the text in different labels or just use a richtextbox.